# Alert in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

In the code below I am trying to disable paste in the Ace Editor (let's say textarea). I want to add alert when user tries to paste. When I added `alert( )` it shows alert indefinitely. I think it's because of `setInterval( )`. But this function does not run if I remove `setInterval( )`. Is there any way to show alert only once when user paste?

```js
var CONTROL_INTERVAL02 = setInterval(function(){

stop = function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}

var el = document.querySelectorAll('.ace_text-input');

if(el.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      el[i].addEventListener('paste', stop, true);
  }

}

});
```

Comment: Did you call the function, after removing `setInterval`?

Comment: It makes no sense to call `setInterval` and then bind event listeners in the callback. This will multiply the listeners indefinitely. Why repeat that at all? Just execute that code once...

Comment: Thanks. I am beginner in JS. Do you mean removing setInterval? It does not work after removing setInterval

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari that's what I am asking, did you call the `CONTROL_INTERVAL02` function after removing the `setInterval`? Can you add the code, that you tried after removing the `setInterval`.

Comment: I mean, remove `setTimeout` and unwrap the code inside the callback function, so that it is not in a function anymore, but main code. "Not work" is not a good problem description. If your document is getting additional elements asynchronously, then you should tell us (I am guessing now). In that case, look up "event delegation".

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I added the code that I tried after removing the setInterval. It's not working. It does not disable paste

Comment: You need to call the function, in the last line call it like this: `CONTROL_INTERVAL02()`. Only after calling the function the code inside it gets executed.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Thanks. I tried with the same as well but still not working. Just wondering in the first line it is set as a variable var CONTROL_INTERVAL02

Comment: Can you provide a runnable snippet (using editor toolbar) inside your question, which reproduces the issue you are rasing?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal "*did you call the CONTROL_INTERVAL02 function*" - `var timer = setInterval(....` will return the timer ID for the setInterval, not a function "to be called".   **EDIT** ah - you probably mean `var func = function() { ... };  func();`  as it would be after "you remove [just] the setInterval` - remove the variable as well, and the `function() { }` wrapper.   OP probably just wants their code in doc.ready.

Comment: If it doesn't work when you remove the setInterval *and* the control_interval02 variable *and* the inline function, then you probably need to wrap your code in document.ready:   `$(function() { stop = function(...` })`

Comment: Use the natural event bubbling and listen to the top element for 'paste'

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by freedomn-m,  After removing `setInterval( )` and wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function() { })` worked.

Answer (score -1):

`setInterval(function, time)` method is used to call **function** in every **time**.

So you have to use the `setTimeout(function, time)` method.